# Basic ajax, trying to POST data to local api file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am following the instruction from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nL7X1UMWsc&index=8&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABdI2V8I_SWo22tFpgh2s6_ and http://rest.learncode.academy/.

I am trying to POST data to my local API file.

The code belows doesn't work with my localhost/api/friends file, but it works perfectly fine if I change the url to http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends.

I checked the network under deverloper tool and it did POST the data, but the data is not written to the file, and it doesn't return the data that I just posted.

```
$(function(){

    var $friends = $('#friends');

    $.ajax({    
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/ajax/api/friends',
        success: function(friends){
            console.log('succuess', friends);
            $.each(friends, function(i, friend){
                $friends.append('<li>id: ' + friend.id + ', name: ' + friend.name +', age: ' + friend.age + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });

    $('#add-friend').on('click', function(){
        var friend = {
            id: $id.val(),
            name: $name.val(),
            age: $age.val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/ajax/api/friends',
            data: friend,
            success: function(newFriend){
                console.log('succuess', newFriend);
            } 
        });

    });
```

This is what my api/friends file looks like

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Will","age":33},{"id":2,"name":"Laura","age":27}]
```

The console log prints

```
succuess [{"id":1,"name":"Will","age":33},{"id":2,"name":"Laura","age":27}]
```

It is not returning the data that I just POST to the file.

Comment: Can you share the server side code from the page to where you post the data? The problem is probably there.

Comment: What you mean server side code? I am nooby, I don't have any php code for this one. This is pretty much all my code. Do I need php to write the data to the file?

Comment: What is the code that is running in the page to where you post data? Javascript is code that runs in the client machine (your browser runs it for you), while PHP, for example, runs in the server's computer.

Comment: This server code would be what actually adds the new friend to the database (or file, in your case). [Client side vs Server side code](http://www.seguetech.com/blog/2013/05/01/client-side-server-side-code-difference)

Comment: I don't think I have any, maybe that is the problem...... It wasn't mentioned in that website and youtube video, so I assume I don't need it. Jquery and HTML is all there is for this one, only two files, one html file and one api file.

Comment: How does this api file look like? I didn't see it in the website. Are you on a Linux or windows machine, does this api have permission to modify the file? And what video are you taking about?

Comment: the api file is just one line, [{"id":1,"name":"Will","age":33},{"id":2,"name":"Laura","age":27}], the video is the youtube video that I am watching, the link is in the description. I am on a windows machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59692/discussion-between-t-pimentel-and-ou-ye).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the GET is working for localhost, but if you don't have anything running as a back-end the POST shouldn't work

Basically the JavaScript/JQuery is code running in your browser that can change the interface and can change your page dynamically, by adding/deleting things to/from parts of it when you click a button, for example.

The server code is what sends you this html/javascript.

And the server code would be the thing that has permission to write on databases/files to change their values or just get them and give them to you.

With ajax you use js to get things dynamically from the server. You send a request to the server, which runs the server code (and changes db values, if needed) and returns some information for the javascript code, which it uses to change how the website looks.